# cssSelector("select[title=\"Sort By\"]")

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

In a selenium script Sorting a dropdown using

`new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[title=\"Sort By\"]"))).selectByVisibleText("Name");`

Can anybody please explain me this part `cssSelector("select[title=\"Sort By\"]"` of above statement.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cssSelector("select[title=\"Sort By\"]")
```

this is one of the technique to locate web element/elements.

You must have heard about xpath, which is one of the way to locate element/elements in a web page.

Further more , `select` is tag in **HTML**. `title` is **attribute** and Sort By is value of attribute.

Just like this :

**HTML** :

```
<select id="sel" class="drop-down" title="Sort By">  
  <options>..</options>
  <options>..</options>
  <options>..</options>
</select>
```

Now If you have to write **cssSelector** , you can write like this :

```
tagname[attribute="attribute value"]  

select[id="sel"]
```

**or**

```
select[class="drop-dwon"]
```

**or**

```
select[title="Sort By"]
```

Hope this will be helpful !

Comment: Thankyou! yes it helps. one more thing why \ is used with Sort By.

Comment: That escapes the quote mark. (because you are already in between two double quotes). So it passes on "Sort By" instead of Sort By

Comment: Or to make it simple, you can use single quote, `select[title='Sort By'] `.  Using Single/Double quote to wrap HTML Tag Attribute value is acceptable in XPath and CSS Selector.

Answer (score 0):

`new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[title=\"Sort By\"]"))).selectByVisibleText("Name");`

You are selecting by CSS selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. The alternative is XPath which is more powerful but harder to learn.

What this part `By.cssSelector("select[title=\"Sort By\"]")` does is select all `select` elements that have `title` attributes set equal to "Sort By". Although by prefixing `driver.findElement(` you are requesting just one element, the first. At least you would be if it was python, Java might differ but was not in your question nor tags.